# Python internal error Handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, clint

I'm having issues with my program just closing at random stages and am not sure why.

At first, I thought it was because it was getting an error but I added an error handle. still for some reason it just closes after say a few days of running and no error is displayed. code below

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import sys
import time
from clint.textui import puts, colored

API_URL = "http://urgmsg.net/livenosaas/ajax/update.php"

class Scraper (object):
    id_stamp = 0

    def __init__(self, timeout, recent_messages=True):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.handlers = []
        self.recent_messages = recent_messages

    def register_handler(self, handler):
        self.handlers.append(handler)
        return handler

    def scrape(self):
        try:
            resp = requests.get(API_URL, params={'f': self.id_stamp}).json()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            puts("Error encountered when connecting to urgmsg: ", newline=False)
            puts(colored.red(e.__class__.__name__), newline=False)
            puts(" " + e.message)
            return

        if not resp['updated']:
            return

        old_id_stamp = self.id_stamp
        self.id_stamp = resp['IDstamp']
        # if old_id_stamp is 0, this is the first scrape
        # which will return a whole bunch of recent past messages
        if not self.recent_messages and old_id_stamp == 0: return

        # Pager messages are returned newest to oldest, we want to
        # process them oldest to newest
        frags = lh.fragments_fromstring(resp['data'])[::-1]
        for frag in frags:
            msg = PagerMessage(frag)
            for handler in self.handlers:
                handler(msg)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.scrape()
            time.sleep(self.timeout)

class PagerMessage:
    def __init__(self, fragment):
        children = fragment.getchildren()
        self.datetime = children[0].text
        self.text = children[1].text
        # channel starts with `- `
        self.channel = children[1].getchildren()[0].text[2:]
        self.response = 'CFSRES' in self.text
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} [{}]: {}".format(self.channel, self.datetime, self.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = Scraper(5)
    @scraper.register_handler
    def handler(msg):
        puts(colored.yellow(msg.channel), newline=False)
        puts(" [", newline=False)
        puts(colored.green(msg.datetime), newline=False)
        puts("] ", newline=False)
        if msg.response:
            puts(colored.red(msg.text))
        else:
            puts(msg.text)
    scraper.run()
```

Have I set this part out wrong ?

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                puts("Error encountered when connecting to urgmsg: ", newline=False)
                puts(colored.red(e.__class__.__name__), newline=False)
                puts(" " + e.message)
                return
```

Comment: It would be hard to answer, because we don't even know what happens. And it's impossible to reproduce the problem. Try to add logging, use broad exception cases and this will help you to know your error.

Comment: OK will read up on how to do logging and how would one add and use a broad exception case?

Comment: Just add extra `except:` with no exception type in the end.

Comment: I'll add as solved if you add that in answer area as I can see what you mean about everyone getting an error

Comment: I really think, that it's an answer. It is just an advice to trace your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sobolevn change

```
except: as e:
                puts("Error encountered", newline=False)
                puts(colored.red(e.__class__.__name__), newline=False)
                puts(" " + e.message)
                return
```

Comment: Sorry can't format from mobile will change once home.